# Вставка прелоудера в текст

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как можно вставить прелоудер в текст между h1 и p, а не по центру всей страницы?

```css
.container{
padding: 0px 20px;
text-align:center;
}

.lds {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  /* left: 0; */
  background: rgba(158, 114, 33, 0.08);
  z-index: 9999999999999999999999999999999999999;
}

.lds-default {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 46.3%;
  z-index: 99999999999;
}

.lds-default div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #ff8643;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-default 1.2s linear infinite;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
  top: 37px;
  left: 66px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.1s;
  top: 22px;
  left: 62px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.2s;
  top: 11px;
  left: 52px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
  top: 7px;
  left: 37px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: -0.4s;
  top: 11px;
  left: 22px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
  top: 22px;
  left: 11px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: -0.6s;
  top: 37px;
  left: 7px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: -0.7s;
  top: 52px;
  left: 11px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(9) {
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
  top: 62px;
  left: 22px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(10) {
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
  top: 66px;
  left: 37px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(11) {
  animation-delay: -1s;
  top: 62px;
  left: 52px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(12) {
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
  top: 52px;
  left: 62px;
}

@keyframes lds-default {
  0%, 20%, 80%, 100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
<div id="lds" class="lds">
  <div class="lds-default">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Тут какой-то текст</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно правильно задать свойства *position*, центрировать с помощью *flex*, указать корректные размеры лоадера... и проблема решается сама собой:

```css
.container {
  padding: 0px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.lds {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(158, 114, 33, 0.08);
}

.lds-default {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.lds-default div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #ff8643;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-default 1.2s linear infinite;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
  top: 37px;
  left: 66px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.1s;
  top: 22px;
  left: 62px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.2s;
  top: 11px;
  left: 52px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
  top: 7px;
  left: 37px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: -0.4s;
  top: 11px;
  left: 22px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
  top: 22px;
  left: 11px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: -0.6s;
  top: 37px;
  left: 7px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: -0.7s;
  top: 52px;
  left: 11px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(9) {
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
  top: 62px;
  left: 22px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(10) {
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
  top: 66px;
  left: 37px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(11) {
  animation-delay: -1s;
  top: 62px;
  left: 52px;
}

.lds-default div:nth-child(12) {
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
  top: 52px;
  left: 62px;
}

@keyframes lds-default {
  0%,
  20%,
  80%,
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <div id="lds" class="lds">
    <div class="lds-default">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Тут какой-то текст</p>
</div>
```